# Factory same ID for a column, auto-incremental, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, faker, laravel-factory

I try to give to a column the ID of that row, witch is autoincremental. Right now are random values .

**//From Factory**

```
    return [
       //code...
       'register_id' => $faker->unique()->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 100),
       //code...
   ];  

    //From Seeder
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Person::class, 100)->create();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/model-factory-increment-value-faker?page=1) , and I edited for my case.

```
$autoIncrement = autoIncrement();

$factory->define(Person::class, function (Faker $faker) use ($autoIncrement) {
    $autoIncrement->next();

    //code

    return [
       'register_id' => $autoIncrement->current(),
    ]

});

function autoIncrement()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
```